# Getting promise instead of an object

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a data from get API request, but I can't.

*// service*

```
function getGithubInfo() {
  return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/test') 
    .success(function(data) { 
      return data; 
    }) 
    .error(function(err) { 
      return err;   
    }); 
};
```

*// controller*

```
function getGithubInfo() {
  vm.githubAccount = contactsService.getGithubInfo();
  console.log(vm.githubAccount);
}
```

I get `Promise {$$state: Object}` in console instead of an `$object`.

> How to get the array of data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are returning`$http` service so you get a promise in return to get data from promise do something like this.

```
  function getGithubInfo() {
      contactsService.getGithubInfo().then(function(res){
            vm.githubAccount = res.data;
            console.log(vm.githubAccount);
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Added the then function, which is fired when we get the response from the Asynchronous service call and the response is wrapped inside the `data` property of promise object.

```
//Service

    function getGithubInfo() {
      return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/test')
        .then(function(response) {    //Added this then  function
          return response.data;
        })
        .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err;   
        }); 
    };
```